# How do I show a modal box on page load using Chakra UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

How do I show a modal box on page load using Chakra UI?

I've tried to find this information on Chakra's documentation without success.

```
import {
    useDisclosure,
    Modal,
    ModalOverlay,
    ModalContent,
    ModalCloseButton,
    ModalBody,
    Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
            
export default function BasicUsage() {
    const { isOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
    
    return (
        <>
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
                <ModalOverlay />
                <ModalContent>
                    <ModalCloseButton />
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Text>Hello</Text>
                    </ModalBody>
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a [`defaultIsOpen`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-disclosure#parameters) property to the `useDisclosure` hook to set the default value for `isOpen`.

Set that property to `true` to have the modal open on page load.

```js
const { isOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure({ defaultIsOpen: true })
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you!